# sql: first row after the last row with a property

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to write a query that returns the first row immediately after the last row with a given property (ordered by id). Id's may not be consecutive.

Ideally it would look something like this:

```
...
JOIN (select max(id) id from my_table where CONDITION) m
JOIN (select min(id) from my_table where id > m.id) n
```

However, I can not use identifier `m` in the second subselect.

It is possible to use nested queries in nested queries, but is there an easier way?

Thank you.

Comment: Define _easier_... Hard to say without seeing the whole picture.

Comment: Please add your sample data with your expected output (in order)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `lead()` to get the next id *before* applying the condition:

```
select t.*
from my_table t join
     (select max(next_id) as max_next_id
      from (select t.*, lead(id) over (order by id) as next_id
            from my_table t
           ) t
      where <condition>
     ) tt
     on t.id = tt.max_next_id;
```

You could also do:

```
select t.*
from my_table t
where t.id > (select max(t2.id) from my_table t2 where <condition>)
order by t2.id asc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Comment: it's a little confusing that you use `t` to replace `my_table` and also as an explicit alias at time in the first code. Also in the first code, you are doing a max on the next_id which means you are losing the current id, and give he join m and n the data from m is not accessible in the rest of the query.

Comment: Wow, I really like the use of FETCH/LIMIT, never occurred to me to put that into a sub-query/CTE.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how this is getting woven into the rest of your query, so I have used a CTE

```
WITH max_next AS (
    SELECT r.id as max_id
        ,r.next_id
    FROM (
        SELECT m.id
            ,m.next_id
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY m.id DESC) AS rn
        FROM (
            SELECT n.* -- to provide data to satisfy CONDITIONS
                ,LEAD(n.id) OVER(ORDER BY n.id) as next_id
            FROM my_table AS n
        ) AS m
        WHERE CONDITIONS
    ) AS r
    WHERE r.rn = 1
)
```

I would also shrink the n.* to the columns needed by CONDITIONS to a, not be implicit as the * slows the compile time down (or historically has) as all meta data needs to be read to understand what columns is in the ANY, and the while the compile can also prune not used columns, it's faster if you just ask for what you want (in best case just a compile time savings, worse case, it read all the data when you only need x number of columns read)

And borrowing from Gordon solution, the `ROW_NUMBER` part could be simpler

```
WITH max_next AS (
    SELECT m.id
        ,m.next_id
        --, plus what ever other things you want from m
    FROM (
        SELECT n.* -- to satisfy CONDITIONS needs
            ,LEAD(n.id) OVER(ORDER BY n.id) as next_id
        FROM my_table AS n
    ) AS m
    WHERE CONDITIONS
    ORDER BY m.id DESC LIMIT 1
)
```

So for an example for @PIG,

```
WITH my_table AS (
    SELECT column1 AS id
        ,column2 AS con1
        ,column3 AS other
    FROM VALUES (1,'a',123),(2,'b',234),(3,'a',345),(5,'b',456),(7,'a',567),(10,'c',678)
)
SELECT m.id
    ,m.next_id
    ,m.other
FROM (
    SELECT n.* -- to satisfy CONDITIONS needs
        ,LEAD(n.id) OVER(ORDER BY n.id) as next_id
    FROM my_table AS n
) AS m
WHERE m.con1 = 'b'
ORDER BY m.id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

gives `5, 7, 456` which is the last `'b'` and the new row, and an extra value on my_table for entertainment purposes (and run on Snowflake to, which means I fixed the prior SQL also.)

Comment: Hi @Simeon Pilgrim Could you please provide sample data , on which i can run your query.

Comment: @PIG I didn't create any, as the SQL seemed simple enough, are you concerned my solution doesn't work? Or would you like me to explain why I think it will work?

Comment: I just wanted to practice with your code for learning purpose.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, it's pretty straightforward (easy), and it's good that you know records may not be stored in a ordered/consecutive fashion.

```
SELECT *
FROM   my_table
WHERE  id = (
  SELECT min(id)
  FROM   my_table
  WHERE  id > (
    SELECT max(id)
    FROM   my_table
    WHERE  CONDITION));
```